TextBox and SetFocus VBA Excel
I have 3 couples of textboxes.
I need to move the cursor on the first textbox  of which the second textbox is not empty.
For example, I have the sixth textbox not empty and I need to move the cursor on the fifth textbox.
I tried using SETFOCUS method but the cursor doesn’t move as I would like.
I use AFTER UPDATE event.
How it is possible to solve this problem?
Following similar code
Private Sub txtMain_AfterUpdate()
 
  Select Case True

        Case  txt2.Text <> ""
                txt1.SetFocus
        Case txt4.Text <> ""
                txt2.SetFocus
        Case txt6.Text <> ""
                txt5.SetFocus
        End Select
End sub

I tried using Change and Exit event

Which code is specifically called or used in the form? Do you have a textbox named txtMain? What do you mean by following similar code? Should one assume that the code you posted is used for the AfterUpdate event of each text box?

HI
the complete code is very long. I use the AFTER UPDATE event also for the other textboxes, and in this case the code that performs other actions works

I am not sure I understand your question... Considering that your above code works, but you want it to be similar for some other check boxes, would it be a correct assumption? If so, you need to supply more pieces of information: The name of the respective text boxes (at least a pattern as they contain text "txtBMain", or something else), the names or specific pattern *for the check boxes to be controlled by each such control. Then, I can help you with a wrapper class able to identify the text box having the necessary After update event and proceed according to **extracted supplied logic **.

I meant, the name of each text box having the example AfterUpdate event must be placed in an array (or you need to supply some logic based on which to be identified when allocating the event code) and another logic to relate the necessary text boxes name used to iterate for setFocus the correct one.

Hi all and thank you everyone.
I have solved using KEYDOWN EVENT.
Thank you

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Assuming it all happens in the form:
Private Sub txtMain_AfterUpdate()
  Dim x As Integer
  Dim txt As MSForms.TextBox
  For x = 2 To 6
    If Controls("txt" & x).Text <> "" Then
      Controls("txt" & (x - 1)).SetFocus
    End If
  Next
End Sub

The idea is to iterate through all textboxes assuming they have same pattern in the name: "txt" + number. The loop starts with second text box because there's no previous textbox before first one.
UPDATE
Private Sub txtMain_AfterUpdate()
  Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control
  Dim txt As MSForms.TextBox
  Dim txtPrev As MSForms.TextBox
  Dim prevTag As String
  For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.TextBox Then
      Set txt = ctrl
      '// Somehow get the value of tag
      prevTag = "GET TAG VALUE OF PREVIOUS TEXTBOX"
      If txt.Text <> "" Then
        Set txtPrev = FindPreviousTextBox(prevTag)
        If Not txtPrev Is Nothing Then
          txtPrev.SetFocus
          Exit For
        End If
      End If
    End If
  Next
End Sub

Private Function FindPreviousTextBox(prevTag As String) As MSForms.TextBox
  Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control
  For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.TextBox Then
      If ctrl.Tag = prevTag Then
        Set FindPreviousTextBox = ctrl
        Exit Function
      End If
    End If
  Next
End Function

If you want to manipulate with tags, you first need to iterate over all controls and check for textboxes. If a control is textbox, then you get the Tag property from it. The only thing is to somehow get the tag value of previous textbox (since I don't know how you do it). I wrote in the comment that you need to do it somehow.

Thank you for your answer. However, since I have more complex names for the textboxes like txtSerialPh and so on, I find it difficult to adapt it. Instead, if I wanted to use the control's tag, would it be possible to iterate using the tag?

Use a control array  instead.
